# How do I map <C-,> and <C-.> in neovim?

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

How do I use `<C-,>` and `<C-.>` to switch between multiple tabs?

Comment: `i_CTRL-V` followed by `CTRL-,` and `CTRL-.` in neovim results in `,` and `.` only, respectively, so it doesn't seem like neovim supports those combinations. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101559/7868781) seems to suggest it may not be possible, but I haven't checked the documentation.

Comment: I've [edit]ed your question to clarify, but I wasn't sure if "tables" was meant to be "tabs." I also removed the second sentence because "setting it like this" didn't appear to refer to any code or mappings, so it wasn't clear.

Comment: @frippe it depends if you are on nvim terminal or nvim-qt/goneovim for instance. The OP asks two different questions: how to map those keys. And how to switch tabs.

Comment: @eyalkarni, the way I read the question and how it's tagged, OP's using `neovim` and already knows how to switch between tabs but wants to create custom keybindings using those specific combinations. Personally, I've been happy with `<M-H>` and `<M-L>` so far.